# One-line foreach loop removes alternative elements in list

Tags: python

How come one-line foreach removes alternative elements in list and not removes everything? or how is the implementation of the foreach loop?

```
aList = ['xyz', 1, 'zara', 2, 'xyz']
for i, ele in enumerate(aList):
    print(i, ele)
    aList.remove(ele)
print(aList)
```

> > 0 xyz
> >
> > 1 zara
> >
> > 2 xyz
> >
> > [1, 2]

Comment: hey @jpp, I don't think that's a very good dup target for this question

Comment: @Jpp i didn't find the answer in what you consider as duplicate

Comment: @jpp I agree that one is better. I still think that neither of them really give a satisfactory answer as to why this goes wrong in the way it does, but unless OP specifically requests that, I am content assuming that they have fixed their problem with those answers

Comment: @jpp I think this example using `enumerate` might be sufficiently weird to deserve its own answer

Comment: @MoxieBall, Fair enough, I'll reopen. I do think OP needs to explain why the duplicate doesn't help them. Otherwise, this is zero-research.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152898/list-remove-skipping-an-item-in-a-list?noredirect=1&lq=1) might be a better dup target. I'm surprised I can't find an SO answer with a step-by-step of exactly why removing elements from a list while iterating makes things happen that people don't expect

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34238688/6779307) gives a pretty good explanation in the second excerpt it quotes.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh not sure which you meant but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207427/9801728) is the one that OP needs to see.

Comment: @MoxieBall I meant this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34238688/6779307

Comment: @jpp here's a proper dup target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list

Comment: @MoxieBall, Yep fine (I can't close now that I've reopened). Main point is I can't think of an answer which doesn't repeat those others. `enumerate` isn't relevant here IMO, but I reopened in case someone wants to explain why it's not relevant.

Comment: @jpp you're right, enumerate isn't relevant, I was mistaken in thinking it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st iteration, access to 1st element of array:
`['xyz', 1, 'zara', 2, 'xyz']` removes xyz => `[1, 'zara', 2, 'xyz']`

2nd iteration, access to 2nd element of array:
`[1, 'zara', 2, 'xyz']` removes zara, because zara is now the 2nd element => `[1, 2, 'xyz']`

3rd and final iteration, access to 3rd element of array:
`[1, 2, 'xyz']` remove xyz => `[1, 2]`